# Upper bound for geometric type equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem with my homework and don't see the answer. Does anyone know of conditions on $a$ ensuring the convergence of

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k?$$

Using the finite geometric series gives

$$(1-a)^{-1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-a^n)$$

which is not summable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$ there is no convergence. Otherwise $\sum a^n\to 1/(1-a) \neq 0$, hence there is no convergence either.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Having computed the inner sum, you can obtain for the outer  $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p} (1-a^n)=1+p-\frac{a^{p+1}-1}{a-1}$$ from which

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k=\frac{a^{p+1}-a (p+1)+p}{(a-1)^2}$$ Check now what happens when $p$ increases.

Comment: Take the sequence $a_n$ given by the fraction above. So $a=1$ is not admissible. For $a\in {[}0,1)$ the sequence tends to infinity as $a_n = a^n(a-1)^{-1} - n(a-1)^{-1}$. Same holds for $a>1$. So the series never converges for positive $a$?